# IE Compatibility mode go to highest possible version

Tags: html, internet-explorer, compatibility, meta-tags

I have a problem with few users in our company as they don't have updated IE on Windows 7 to the highest version which also supports IE compatibility view EDGE. What I want to ask, how it is possible to fall back to the highest version user has installed ?

I am thinking of

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,IE=8" />
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

"IE=edge" *is* how you tell Internet Explorer to use its highest version rather than any older version. Every version of IE that supports the X-UA-Compatible header supports "IE=edge".

For example, "IE=edge" will tell IE11 to render as IE11, IE10 to render as IE10, IE9 to render as IE9, and IE8 to render as IE8.

Developers who are new to X-UA-Compatible and reading this today may be confused by the use of the word "edge" — the X-UA-Compatible header was introduced in IE8, which is at least 6 years older than the new Windows 10 browser Microsoft Edge, and "edge" in this case refers to "the latest, 'cutting-edge' version of IE's rendering engine". It is not at all related to Microsoft Edge, and for obvious reasons you cannot actually tell IE to render as Microsoft Edge.