# getElementById fails on very specific ID that is definitively in the DOM tree on IE 11, possibly Edge - why?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, getelementbyid

In Microsoft IE and (according to comments) Edge, `getElementById()` on an ID that is exactly "extTabsBodyEleFile1273551781_renderTo" fails.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="extTabsBodyEleFile1273551781_renderTo"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This ID was automatically generated. Changing the ID in any way fixes the problem. Getting the parent of the div and listing its child nodes also includes the div.

The error could be reproduced on both IE 11.0.9600.19155 and 11.0.9600.18538 - but it worked on another machine with IE 11...19155 without issues.

The error can also be reproduced if you open the developer console on a random site, change the ID of any element in the DOM explorer to the ID above and then try to get that element by `document.getElementById('extTabsBodyEleFile1273551781_renderTo')`

I realize that it is an Edge bug and fixing it would just mean changing the ID. My question is why it happens, why it didn't happen on one instance of Edge (I couldn't find setting differences) and how I could generate the ID to ensure it doesn't happen again. It's easy to change it at this place, but without knowing why it happened, it could happen again.

Is there a known hash or number combination an ID is not supposed to have? Is it a legacy setting that I could potentially turn off using meta tags?

I hope this question is not too unspecific for SO - Searching for it proved fruitless because of the legion of getElementById-related questions.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('extTabsBodyEleFile1273551781_renderTo'));
```

```html
<div id="extTabsBodyEleFile1273551781_renderTo"></div>
```

---

Update:

It seems the ID fails in a case insensitive matter:

```
extTabsBodyEleFile1273551781_renderTo
exttabsbodyelefile1273551781_renderto
EXTTABSBODYELEFILE1273551781_RENDERTO
ExttAbsbOdyELEfILE1273551781_rEndErtO
```

All cause the error.

---

Update:

IE Developer console seems to be at least involved in the error.
Opening a test HTML page that displays the result of trying to retrieve an Element by that ID inside itself instead of logging it to the console works as expected if IE was started with the console closed - until the console is opened and the page refreshed a couple (1-5) of times, whereupon the error appears again and persists until IE is closed and reopened. Closing the developer console after the error appeared seems not to have an effect.

Test HTML is hosted at [netlify](http://festive-albattani-f9a6f4.netlify.com/), HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;}
            th, td {padding: 15px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="extTabsBodyEleFile1273551781_renderTo"></div>
        <div><p id="testresult"></p></div>
        <script>
        var testresults = document.getElementById('testresult');
        var time = new Date().getTime();
        testresults.innerHTML = "<h3>testresults:</h3><br><table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Result</th><th>Time</th></tr>" +
        '<tr><td>extTabsBodyEleFile1273551781_renderTo: ' + "</td><td>" + document.getElementById('extTabsBodyEleFile1273551781_renderTo') + "</td><td>" + time + "</td></tr>" +
        '<tr><td>extTabsBodyEleFile1273551781_renderTo through querySelector: ' + "</td><td>" + document.querySelector('*[id="extTabsBodyEleFile1273551781_renderTo"]') + "</td><td>" + time + "</td></tr>" +
        '</table>';
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This can be reproduced in EdgeHTML, but are you sure you're not getting IE and Edge mixed up? Those version strings correspond to IE11 on Windows 8.1. Edge is not a Windows 8.1 browser.

Comment: `SCRIPT5022: SCRIPT5022: SecurityError` :-!

Comment: I created a Microsoft Feedback hub item: https://aka.ms/AA37zmi - it might help to vote on it

Comment: @BoltClock You are correct, it's IE 11. Possibly got confused by the "Document Mode: Edge" in the emulation tab in the developer tools. Edited accordingly

Comment: I tested it with Edge and there it happens too. I suspect that IE uses the Edge Engine when using "Document Mode: Edge".

Comment: @Peter B: IE does not use EdgeHTML in Edge mode. The Edge mode existed 6 years before Microsoft Edge or Windows 10, and has nothing to do with the new browser. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51397877/ie-compatibility-mode-go-to-highest-possible-version/51398546#51398546

Comment: I can reproduce it in the question snippet but not in a simple HTML document. Perhaps it has to do with the iframe?

Comment: @Álvaro González no, happens in its own HTML as well - https://i.imgur.com/iMAQEQJ.png

Comment: @Álvaro González same result https://i.imgur.com/9UuYJRN.png

Comment: @Klaue I was trying in [Edge](https://i.imgur.com/5v9L9dy.png), I hadn't realised the question has been moving towards IE11.

Comment: @Álvaro González yeah, that was an error on my part, but some people seemed to be able to reproduce it on Edge as well

Comment: @Anuga thanks to your late answer, I tried some more and found out that it's case insensitive - same string produces the errors, but you can mix cases as you like

Comment: I have built a script to generate random strings for IDs and to check if they can be selected that way or not. Every single one of them could, except `extTabsBodyEleFile1273551781_renderTo`. And I've generated millions of them.

Comment: Have you tried an id with the same string length and see what happens? You mentioned that removing a character makes it work, what happens if you add one?

Comment: @Giwrgos Lampadaridis removing one, adding one or changing one (save for case) all make it work

Comment: @ritaj user3052629 from the answer below found 2 more with only a single number change

Comment: Alternate means work: `document.querySelector('*[id="extTabsBodyEleFile1273551781_renderTo"]')`. I suspect this has something to do with the validity checks that `getElementById` does.

Comment: @PeterB Wow. That page says: "This content is available only in the FeedbackHub app through the *[sic]* Windows 10." So much for the open web, and for grammar.

Comment: What's actually generating that ID, though? Because this feels very much like some kind of MS-specific application magic.

Comment: @Boann: Feedback Hub isn't intended to be a web app to begin with. It's a Windows 10 feature. Ideally, HTTP links to Feedback Hub wouldn't even exist, and in fact it does use its own URL scheme. I don't know why Microsoft creates aka.ms links that point to HTTP redirects to Feedback Hub. Having said that, there is a web-based channel that should be used to report Edge bugs instead of Feedback Hub (at least, that's what the Edge team tells me). [I've reported this issue there.](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/19644101)

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans it's generated by me, not by anything ms-specific. As said, I could change it, but as long as I don't know what the cause actually was and how to avoid the issue, that seems just a delay before the issue springs up somewhere again, I have thousands of generated IDs in my webapp

Comment: No, that's fair, but this is not the kind of id that you normally generate. A normal id is something like `file-field-1`, whatever you wrote to generate it came up with some really curious HTML element ids =)

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans  well it's the div the body of the Ext (Ext JS) Tab of file number 1273551781 (tab body itself having the ID extTabsBodyEleFile1273551781) is supposed to be rendered into

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

It looks like there are specific strings edge return null if you try to select them, there are 3 strings i found that can't be selected in this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/cogwrudx/4/

I have run tests from 1273 to 1290 ids and found only 3, but i guess there could be more, I don't know why those strings so important that edge doesn't allows to search for them.

**Origin**

I can't comment but this was really annoying me so I had to do some more testings, and it looks like no matter what changes you will do to this string it will work, but it will NOT work for this exact string.

Adding/removing any letter/number will work.
Changing the last number before the underscore to 2 instead of 1 will work as well.
In fact changing any number to a different number works.

It looks like edge doesn't like that specific string for a reason and I really want to know why.

**EDIT 1**

After doing some more basic testing I have run the next fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/cogwrudx/4/

As you can see after running it and looking the console, there are 2 more ids he doesn't find:

```
not found:  extTabsBodyEleFile1273351781_renderTo
not found:  extTabsBodyEleFile1273451781_renderTo
not found:  extTabsBodyEleFile1273551781_renderTo
```

So from this i think there is no obvious pattern to avoid as others suggested, but a very specific strings to search for, as if you try to set the same strings as classes it will not work as well.

**FYI**

I was testing this on Edge browser on Windows 10, and not IE11.

```
Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0
Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134
```

Comment: Same for me, not least so that it won't happen again - there must be a pattern to avoid

Comment: See my update, i did found some extra strings it doesn't work for @Klaue

Comment: can confirm your update with IE 11. Curious. Running the test again starting from  1274.. got no results.

Comment: Because all of the ids of 1274 are "selectable", i did some tests from 1273 to 1290 and found only those 3 ids that edge couldn't handle them, i'm sure you can find more of those if you keep looking.

Comment: I will try to inform the MSFT developers about this issue via internal Chanel.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Thx, I would really like to know why this happens so i hope you can share your findings here.

Comment: @ Art3mix, I will try to inform you once I get any information from the senior engineers.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT still no answer? the problem persists

Comment: @Kadser, You can see that Peter B had already submitted this issue to Microsoft via Feedback Hub. MS Edge developer will try to check it and try to correct the issue soon. You can expect that this issue can be corrected in future Edge updates.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I have no access to that as I don't have windows 10, but I checked it a few days back when I had and there was no answer, that's why I asked - if there was any new info I wasn't aware of

Comment: @Kadser, Till now I did not get any new information from developers regarding this issue. I will try to notify you if I get any news about it. Thanks for your understanding.